# Entity Framework does not save property of same type

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following classes

```
    public class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int ParentId { get; set; }
    }

public class Transaction
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string Payee { get; set; }
        public string Memo { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
        public Category SubCategory { get; set; }
   }
```

And the database created is created properly
[SQL Server Table Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvKm7.png)

The problem is that on SaveChanges, EF sets the Category property data but does not set SubCategory. I looked at explicitly setting Foreign Keys but was not successful in doing it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share the code where you're trying to call `SaveChanges()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have one reference to a related entity, EF can generally work out or assign the FK name via convention. It does this based on the type name, not the property name. When you want two references to the same related entity type, you need to explicitly map the FK to use.  Since you're not declaring the FK properies inside your entity (which is good IMO) you will need to map them (EF6) or declare shadow properties for them (EF Core)

For instance assuming your Transaction table will have a CategoryId and a SubCategoryId column, using the `modelBuilder` in the context's `OnModelCreating` event:

[EF6]

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction>
    .HasRequired(x => x.Category)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(x => x.MapKey("CategoryId"));
modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction>
    .HasRequired(x => x.SubCategory)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(x => x.MapKey("SubCategoryId"));
```

If the category and/or SubCategory is optional, replace `HasRequired` with `HasOptional`.

[EF Core]

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction>
    .HasOne(x => x.Category)
    .WithMany()
    .IsRequired()
    .HasForeignKey("CategoryId");
modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction>
    .HasOne(x => x.SubCategory)
    .WithMany()
    .IsRequired()
    .HasForeignKey("SubCategoryId");
```

If it is optional, remove the `.IsRequired()`.

ModelBuilder can be rather clunky, so for anything other than the most simple schema I use entity type configuration declarations to explicitly configure the schema rather than rely on convention or modelBuilder.